# EmeditorでGoogleドライブのファイルで「ファイルから置換」がエラーになる

Tags: emeditor

Emeditor(20.6.0)でGoogleドライブのファイルに対して「ファイルから置換」を行うと、
*** MapViewOfFile 関数がエラーを返しました。 *** / 要求された操作はユーザー マップ セクションで開いたファイルでは実行できません。
のエラーが出て実行できないのですが、レジストリやセキュリティーの設定等で使えるようにすることはできますか。
Windows Defenderをオフにしても同様のエラーです。
パソコン版GoogleドライブでGドライブにマウントされたファイルに対して操作をしています。
Dropboxでは便利に使えてPC間で共有できていた機能で、何とかして使いたいのですが、、、

Answer (score 1):

EmEditor は最新版に更新し、[カスタマイズ] ダイアログの [ファイル] ページで、[大きなファイルを保存時、ファイル マッピングを有効にする] をオフにしてみてください。また、[ファイルから置換] ダイアログの [変更したファイルを開いたままにする] のオプションを変更してみてください。

Comment: [大きなファイルを保存時、ファイル マッピングを有効にする] をオフ
でファイルからの一括置換ができるようになりました。
ありがとうございました。